# When working with access and mysql is there a way to view which queries are used to generate a pivot table?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, ms-access

How can I determine which sql queries are being used to generate the data?

Answer (score 1):

MySql has a "processlist" command which can show you the running queries. If you can catch the query as it runs you could see what it's doing.

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll give it a try, there has to be a better way.